# Reinstall crashlytics through fabric

Tags: crashlytics, twitter-fabric

I accidentally deleted some `crashlytics` files out of my `xcode` project and now my app wont launch.

```
Header 'Crashlytics.h' not found
Could not build Objective-C module 'Crashlytics'
```

How can I reinstall `crashlytics`? `Fabric` still thinks it is installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By going through the installation process again I was able to reinstall it.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of people are facing the same issue (myself included). Here is a support thread over at twitter with a few suggestions.

[Link to twitter support thread](https://twittercommunity.com/t/stuck-on-build-your-project-after-upgrading-crashlytics-to-fabric/31428/42)